# Adding based on column name not number

Tags: r

I am adding together columns with the following code:

```
cbind(rowSums(data[,c(5,10,11,15)],na.rm=TRUE),rowSums(data[,c(3,6,7)],na.rm=TRUE))
```

But I want to add the columns based upon the column name not their number to eliminate confusion....

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, just replace the numbers with the column names in quotes:

```
 cbind(rowSums(data[,c('elephant','giraffe')],na.rm=TRUE),
       rowSums(data[,c('fish','penguin','albatross')],na.rm=TRUE))
```

I'm collecting data on animal species today. Not sure why I'm adding them together.